# Unable to access WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a webservice @ http://recpushdata.cyndigo.com/Jobs.asmx but I'm not able to access it though I am adding it as a WebReference properly.

Any Help would be great.

Comment: Could you provide more information on why you cannot access it.  Perhaps an error message?

Answer (score 1):

AFAI can see, the asmx page has server errors, so you will not be able to access it.
Contact the admin of the web service to fix the errors.

Comment: http://recpushdata.cyndigo.com/Jobs.asmx access this url it shows all the methods properly

Comment: The Service description doesn't appear to work, and the webservice appears to be configured incorrectly.  
I agree that you need to contact the web-service admin.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you are getting the "The test form is only available for requests from the local machine." error when accessing a method?
If so, you need to add the following into your <system.web> part of your web.config

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

This enables you to access the method from the local machine